# Google Analytics not receiving Android hits

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm having problems with Google Analytics after a change in the Analytics property.

The fact is that the App is sending everythig fine (at least it seems to be fine) but I can't see anything on Analytics - Real time.

I have to add that Property changes, that implied the change of the ID, were made 1 week ago.

That's logcat output from 2 consecutive views:

```
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[client_id_fetcher,5,main]: Loaded client id from disk.
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
I/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@b3e9a1f0
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=screenview,  ht=xxxxx,  sr=xxxxx,  a=xxxxx,  an=xxxxx,  tid=xxxxx,  aid=xxxxx,  cid=xxxxx,  av=2.05,  _u=.2nK-AL,  cd=xxxxx,  
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
V/GAV4(1621): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=screenview,  ht=xxxxx,  sr=xxxxx,  a=xxxxx,  an=xxxxx,  tid=xxxxx,  aid=xxxxx,  cid=xxxxx,  av=2.05,  _u=.K-AL,  cd=xxxxx,  
W/GAV4(701): Thread[Thread-157,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com
```

From logcat I think that all it's OK.

Any suggestion on what cold be worng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've should checked that before.

The problem was that the lib wasn't added to Build Path, so adding it fixes my problem.

I hope it helps to someone.

Comment: You were missing path to your library and still you got that output - connected to service, build hits, etc... ? That doesnt seem right. Please provide more detailed answer..

Comment: @rouen The only thing I did was right-clicking on analytics jar > Add to Build Path. I really don't know if the solution was adding the lib to build path or simply the recompilation (eclipse is doing weird things more and more)